# Calculating limit of a sum by turning it into an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Prove $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}} = \frac{\pi}{6} $$

by changing the expression into an integral.

My idea is that since $\arcsin'(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$, I can turn the above into $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\arcsin'(\frac{k}{2n})$

Also, since $sin(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{1}{2}$ I should somehow turn the above into some an integral like $\int{\arcsin'(\frac{1}{2}})$ since this equals to $\frac{\pi}{6}$.
However, I am stuck at the 'somehow' step where I am supposed to turn it into an integral.
Can someone give me some hints on how to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: $\frac1{\sqrt{1-(k/2n)^2}}\neq\frac1{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}}$.

Comment: Hint : look up "Riemann sums"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an integral say be represented by the Riemann sum:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim\limits_{|\Delta x_i|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i^*)\Delta x_i$$
Where the sum will vary depending on $x_i^*$ and where it is within the particular interval, but as $|\Delta x_i|\to 0$ all sums will converge on the same value.

In your case, we are trying to work back from the sum to the integral, so we will try and rearrange it to a form where it looks like the one above:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2(1-(k/2n)^2)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(k/2n)^2}}\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(k/2n)^2}}\frac{1/2-0}{n}$$
now if we take the limit of the sum you should see it is the equivalent of:
$$\int\limits_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 - (\frac{k}{n})^2}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$